# dropdown width increases in IE11 when focus is in textbox with a placeholder

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

When the focus is in the `<input>` and I click on the `<select>` dropdown then the dropdown's width is increased.
I tried to set the width on focus to 100%, but that's not working.

This is my html:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="hello" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi did you find the solution for this?

Comment: the answer mentioned below done the trick for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the onmousedown attribute and have it focus on the select dropdown so that it loses focus from the input box. For some reason focus on the input before accessing that select causes this error.

`<select onmousedown="$(this).focus()">`

Comment: Doesn't need jquery, <select onmousedown="this.focus()"> works also