# Drop Down width increases automatically in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, html

I have a drop down list and text box placed next to it. When I click first on text box without typing any letters and next click on drop down(Your immediate click should be only on drop down not else where on the form). At this time I could see the width of the drop down gets increased and hovers the text box. I need to avoid doing this and maintain the same width of the drop down. This issue is happening only in IE 11

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select name="SearchScope" title="Search Scope" id="idSearchScope" style="width: 200px !important">
    <option value="/locator.aspx?name=Common.Search.Global.MainPage">All of these words</option>
    <option value="/locator.aspx?name=Common.Search.Global.MainPage">Any of these words</option>
</select>
<input type="text" style="width: 200px" value="" placeholder="Enter text to search"><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: when I remove the place holder form the text I don't find this issue. Is there any work around on how I can maintain the same width of the drop down. After clicking first on text box and next on drop down list without removing the place holder for the text box?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802752/dropdown-width-increases-in-ie11-when-focus-is-in-textbox-with-a-placeholder) solved this problem for me. Quoting [meeebee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151014/meebee),

> Add the onmousedown attribute and have it focus on the select dropdown so that it loses focus from the input box. For some reason focus on the input before accessing that select causes this error.
>
> `<select onmousedown="$(this).focus()">`

Answer (score -1):

Add this CSS code before `</head>`:

```
<style> 
    #idSearchScope option{ width: 200px !important; }
</style>
```

This is because you want to control the width of the options.

Comment: Explain the down vote please so I can review or edit my answer.

Comment: CSS rules don't have quotes and style etc. { style="width: 200px !important" } -> { width: 200px !important; }

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't saw that!!!!!  ... thanks, going to edit now! Ok, done!