# IE 11 dropdown width increase on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Issue is select box option width increases first time on page load. When clicked on one of the options it resizes to the original length of content.

I have tried below solutions, but none of them works for me. All other browsers behave correct.

Option 1: HTML min/max widths

```
<select id="selectbox" style="min-width: 200px; width: auto;">
    <option>Please select delivery address</option>
    <option>1212 Long long address</option>
</select>
```

Option 2: Window onload - setting style.width

```
var d = document.getElementById("selectbox");
d.style.width = "auto";
```

This is the problem, options width is extra large than the contents:
[image]

Changes to normal if selected the the option or clicked outside and clicked back on dropdown
[image]

I've checked these answers.

[Drop Down width increases automatically in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623585/drop-down-width-increases-automatically-in-ie-11) - This one's opposite of what I want.

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/fix-for-ie-select-dropdown-with-fixed.html - Tried this one but didn't work.

Comment: could you share exact code and output using snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: When trying the same code in jsfiddle and IE it was working fine. Then I investigated more in my code, deleting HTML code one by one. I found that the issue was previous form(which was hidden in DOM) in the page getting focus on page load. Added display:none to form tag and focus to drop down which has fixed the problem.
Thanks for your help.